# How do I change the style of Autocomplete TextField (ControlFX)?

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I have an Autocomplete TextField from controlsFX and I want to change the size and the color of each item.

This is my part of code :

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(txt_numberOfCard_GENERAL, cardNumber);
```

[image]

Comment: What did you mean with different color the color of item or text ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :**

Autocomplete from **ControlFX** is a Popup window contains ListView ,the default [css style](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/692/styles-for-auto-completion-popup-are-not) of AutoComplete is :

```
/**
 * Style based on Modena.css combo-box-popup style
 */

.auto-complete-popup > .list-view {
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(to bottom,
        derive(-fx-color,-17%),
        derive(-fx-color,-30%)
        ),
        -fx-control-inner;
    -fx-background-insets: -1 -2 -1 -1, 0 -1 0 0;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) , 12, 0.0 , 0 , 8 );
}
.auto-complete-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 4 0 4 5;
    /* No alternate highlighting */
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background;
}
.auto-complete-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background:  -fx-selection-bar-non-focused;
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-background;
}
.auto-complete-popup  > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:hover,
.auto-complete-popup  > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected:hover {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
}
.auto-complete-popup > .list-view > .placeholder > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);
}
```

So you need to override this class in your Stylesheet file,or by changing the style from your java code like this :

```
        AutoCompletePopup<String> autoCompletePopup = new AutoCompletePopup<>();
        autoCompletePopup.getSuggestions().addAll("Fruit", "Fruits", "Frites", "Cheese!");
        autoCompletePopup.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background:WHITE;"
                + "-fx-accent: #E8EAF6;"
                + "-fx-selection-bar-non-focused:red;"
                + "-fx-font:18px 'Arial'");
            autoCompletePopup.show(textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `TextFields.bindAutoCompletion`

I wanted the autocompletion to be the same size as the text field. After some research, I found that the `bindAutoCompletion` method returns a `AutoCompletionBinding` object. With this object I did just that to keep with the same size:

```java
AutoCompletionBinding<Unidade> autoComplete = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(this.txtField,units);
            autoComplete.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.txtField.widthProperty());
```

If you need to style the object, you can grab the AutoComplete Object and them add classes or even style it directly:

```java
AutoCompletePopup<Unidade> autoCompletionPopup = autoComplete.getAutoCompletionPopup();
autoCompletionPopup.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: BOLD; -fx-font-size: 23; -fx-background-color: #EDECEC;");
// or with the following class: .itemMenu { -fx-font-weight: BOLD; }

// you can clear default styles too
//autoCompletionPopup.getStyleClass().clear();
            autoCompletionPopup.getStyleClass().add("itemMenu");
```

Answer (score 0):

i just little modify Antonio Lucas's Answer because some styling shows me "lication Thread"

Following are my code
AutoCompletePopup autoCompletionPopup = autoComplete.getAutoCompletionPopup();
autoCompletionPopup.setStyle("-fx-font:18px 'arial'");