# Javafx - ComboBox CSS works with Down Arrow not Auto completion

Tags: css, javafx, combobox

**Context:** CSS Styling of combobox dropdown list. The CSS styling on the drop down list works when clicking down arrow.

**Issue:** Unable to change the background color & text color when I start typing in the combobox (auto-completion) as seen below when I click on down arrow

I checked a few links eg: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47609172/3127144) Also tried with a few combinations in combo-box-base, but don't seem to get it working. Hope the issue faced is clear

**CSS Code:**

```
.combo-box-popup > .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-custom1;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-custom1;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-customText;
}
```

Clicking down arrow

[image]

Typing in combobox

[image]

**Edit - Added:**

If anyone has any further inputs / resolution steps to - [Link](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/692/styles-for-auto-completion-popup-are-not) please update. I believe the issue faced is the same as the CSS styling on Autocompletion in ControlsFx does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you using ComboBox of ControlFX ?

Comment: No I am using the 1 which comes with javafx.scene.control

Comment: The auto-completion feature is from ControlFx (TextFields.bind....), I guess that is causing it. I checked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734595/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-autocomplete-textfield-controlfx but setting the background color in .auto-complete-popup .list-view .list-cell also not helping. Any ideas

Comment: Did you try my answer on that thread and it does not give you any effect ?!

Comment: Yes I did & it still does not give the desired effect. I have updated the main qns. where a bug was reported on this specific topic & there was no response to it.